# Scala - Get files based on name pattern

Tags: scala

I would like to filter the files based on some patterns like :

```
 - Team_*.txt (e.g.: Team_Orlando.txt);
 - Name.*.City.txt (e.g.: Name.Robert.California.txt);
```

Or any name (the pattern * . * - it has spaces because was broken my text).

All the filters come from a database table and they are dynamic.

I'm trying to avoid use commands from SO like **cp** or **mv**. Is possible to filter files using patterns like the above ?

Here is what i've tried but got a regex error:

```
  def getFiles(dir:File, filter:String) = {                                           
    (dir.isDirectory, dir.exists) match {                                             
      case (true, true) =>                                                            
        dir.listFiles.filter(f => f.getName.matches(filter))                          
      case _ =>                                                                       
        Array[File]()                                                                 
    }                                                                                 
  }
```

Comment: What error did you get? Maybe your regexp is not regexp, i.e. "Team_*.txt" is not a valid regexp, "Team_.*\.text" is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use java.nio `Files.newDirectoryStream()` for that, it will accept pattern in desired format:

```
val stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, pattern)
```

Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html#glob for detailed description.